# SQL Date Query using parameters - Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access

I have an SQL Query (MS Access), and I want to add the Date() function into a parameter, however I get the error: `[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`
Here is the code:

```
Qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Bookings.Date, Bookings.WeekDay, Bookings.Shift, Bookings.Start, Bookings.Finish,'
    + ' Bookings.DateFinish, Wards.WardName'
    + ' FROM Bookings'
    + ' INNER JOIN Wards ON Bookings.WardNo = Wards.WardNo'
    + ' WHERE (Bookings.NurseNo=:nurseID) AND (Bookings.Date BETWEEN :dateA AND :dateB)'
    + ' ORDER BY Bookings.Date ASC;';

Qry.Params.ParamByName('dateA').Value := 'Date()';
Qry.Params.ParamByName('dateB').Value := 'Date()+6';
```

I've also tried `Qry.Params.ParamByName('dateA').AsString := 'Date()';` but no luck with that, is there a correct way to do this, or would it actually have to be in the query and not parameterised? The reason I want to do it like this, is I will have multiple different queries based on which button is pressed, but the only thing changing is those parameterised dates.

Comment: If you mean Delphi `Date` function, why not `Qry.Params.ParamByName('dateA').Value := Date;`?

Comment: @Zhorov what's the difference between `Date;` and `Date();`? thought it would be the same thing?

Comment: The difference here is between `'Date()'` and `Date`. If I understand your code correctly, just past the result from Delphi's `date` function as a value for your parameter.

Comment: @Zhorov ah okay that has worked!, I'm sure I tried that before, but I must've used Qry.Params.ParamByName('dateA').AsString := Date();, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parameter can't be a function, it has to be a value. You are assigning strings as those values, and those strings do not represent valid dates. That is why you are getting a mismatch error.

You can use Delphi `Date()` function, and pass the returned `TDate` as a parameter value:

```
Qry.Params.ParamByName('dateA').Value := Date();
Qry.Params.ParamByName('dateB').Value := Date()+6;
```

Or, you can use Access's `Date()` function in the SQL itself:

```
Qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT Bookings.Date, Bookings.WeekDay, Bookings.Shift, Bookings.Start, Bookings.Finish,'
    + ' Bookings.DateFinish, Wards.WardName'
    + ' FROM Bookings'
    + ' INNER JOIN Wards ON Bookings.WardNo = Wards.WardNo'
    + ' WHERE (Bookings.NurseNo=:nurseID) AND (Bookings.Date BETWEEN Date() AND Date() + 6)'
    + ' ORDER BY Bookings.Date ASC;';
```